# How can I do boolean logic on two columns in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, select, boolean

I want to do a select in MySql that combines several columns... something like this pseudocode:

```
SELECT payment1_paid AND payment2_paid AS paid_in_full 
FROM denormalized_payments 
WHERE payment1_type = 'check';
```

**Edit**: payment1_paid and payment2_paid are booleans.

I can't use any other language for this particular problem than MySql.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit**: Sorry to everybody who gave me suggestions for summing and concatenating, but I've voted those early answers up because they're useful anyway. And **thanks** to everybody for your incredibly quick answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, for logical and you can do

```
Select (payment1_paid && payment2_paid) as paid_in_full 
from denormalized_payments 
where payment1_type = 'check';
```

As seen [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and).

Comment: Excellent. That's what I needed, with the MySql reference to boot! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
Select CONCAT(payment1_paid, payment2_paid) as paid_in_full 
from denormalized_payments 
where payment1_type = 'check';
```

You can concat any number of field you want.

Answer (score 2):

If by combine you mean concatenate then this will work:

```
select concat(payment1_paid, payment2_paid) as paid_in_full
from denormalized_payments where payment1_type = 'check';
```

If by combine you mean add, then this should work:

```
select payment1_paid + payment2_paid as paid_in_full
from denormalized_payments where payment1_type = 'check';
```

[EDIT]

For boolean AND:

```
select payment1_paid && payment2_paid as paid_in_full
from denormalized_payments where payment1_type = 'check';
```

Comment: thanks, sorry the question was about booleans but that wasn't clear until later. great answer!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but do you mean to concatenate?

```
SELECT CONCAT(ColumnA, ColumnB) AS ColumnZ
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT IF(payment1_paid = 1 AND payment2_paid = 1, 1, 0) AS paid_in_fill`

Answer (score 0):

If are Strings (or you want to treat like Strings the columns that you want to combine) you can use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
select (payment1_paid && payment2_paid) as paid_in_full
from denormalized_payments where payment1_type = 'check';
```

Comment: Actually, It you should go with the Logical AND (&&) as @Robert Gamble mentioned since it should allow short circuit evaluation. Thus if payment1_paid is false, it's false.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and