# How do I do boolean logic on two columns in MySql, one of which is a Varchar?

Tags: mysql, select, field

This is the sequel to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248683/how-can-i-do-boolean-logic-on-two-columns-in-mysql).

I would like to combine three columns into one on a MySql select. The first two columns are boolean and the third is a string, which is sometimes null. This causes strange results:

```
Select *, (payment1_paid && ((payment2_paid || payment2_type ="none"))) as paid_in_full from payments
```

**Note:** `payment1_paid` is boolean, `payment2_paid` is boolean, `payment2_type` is varchar.

**Note:** Please ignore how ridiculous the structure of this table is. Behind every piece of bad code there is a long explanation :)

**Edit:** Null is not interesting to me for the varchar value. I only want to know if it's really "none."

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If null is not interesting then for you then:

```
Select *, 
      (payment1_paid && ((payment2_paid || (payment_type IS NOT NULL && payment_type="none"))) 
         as paid_in_full 
from payments
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want NULL to be false? Try  `(payment_paid IS NULL || payment2_type = "none")`

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *, 
      (payment1_paid && ((payment2_paid || coalesce(payment2_type,"null") ="none"))) 
         as paid_in_full 
from payments
```