# First non-false value

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to simplify the following?

```
CASE WHEN 
    (a.is_future_release IS TRUE OR aa.is_future_release IS TRUE) THEN TRUE 
    ELSE FALSE
END
```

In python I'd do:

```
a.is_future_release or aa.is_future_release or False
```

Can this be simplified in mysql/sql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do boolean logic on two columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248683/how-can-i-do-boolean-logic-on-two-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: @DanielA.White but if I do `a.is_future_release|aa.is_future_release` if both of them evaluate to false it returns `NULL` not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this do what you want?

```
(a.is_future_release OR aa.is_future_release)
```

In MySQL, booleans are treated as integers, with a value of "1" for true and "0" for false.

The only difference between this and your original query is that this could return `NULL` if both values are `NULL`.

Comment: You could wrap the whole thing in `COALESCE(<your term>,0)` to avoid returning a `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

An `IF` statement is a bit cleaner:

```
IF(a.is_future_release IS TRUE OR aa.is_future_release IS TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Or using the boolean operators / shorthand:

```
IF(a.is_future_release|aa.is_future_release, TRUE, FALSE)
```